# Append Quotes for all VARCHAR Columns when exporting to csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, export-to-csv, autosys

I have a stored procedure which when run gives a table output. I want to export this procedure to a csv file but want to append double/single quotes for all the columns with a datatype CHAR/VARCHAR.

For Example:

Stored Proc O/P:

```
ID    Name    Address                  SSN
1      abd    9301,LeeHwy, 22031       64279100
```

Output in CSV File:

```
 1,"abd","9301,LeeHwy, 22031",64279100
```

Can anyone also help me on how I can use a BAT file to execute the procedure and generate this csv file.

Comment: Quick and dirty way, create a view and wrapping your varchar fields with '"' + fieldname + '"'

Comment: @Rogala: That is definitely one way. But I have like 62 columns out of which around 40 are VARCHAR columns. So looking for a way that I can automate it.

Comment: You could get the table schema, and then loop through the records to locate the varchar columns.  Store your script in a local variable, and then execute the script using EXEC @script.  I've done this for other solutions, and it works great!

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. 
Credits also go to @Rogala (The developer who gave initial answer to the question) for triggering the idea of using system tables.

The code is as below:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(Max) = '[Put your table name here]';
DECLARE @currColumns VARCHAR(Max) = NULL;
Declare @Delim CHAR(5)='''"''+'

SELECT @currColumns = COALESCE(@currColumns + ','+ CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE= 'varchar' THEN '''"'' + ' ELSE '' END + '[', '[') + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
                    + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' THEN '+ ''"''' ELSE '' END + ' as [' + COLUMN_NAME + ']' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE  table_name = @tableName 

Set @currColumns= @Delim+@currColumns

EXEC('SELECT ' + @currColumns + ' FROM ' + @tableName);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is to loop through the table schema to extract the varchar columns.  I have tested this for one of my tables, and it worked:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(Max) = '[Put your table name here]';
DECLARE @currColumns VARCHAR(Max) = NULL;

SELECT @currColumns = COALESCE(@currColumns + ',' 
    + CASE WHEN t.Name  = 'varchar' THEN '''"'' + ' ELSE '' END 
    + '[', '[') + c.name + ']' 
    + CASE WHEN t.Name = 'varchar' THEN '+ ''"''' ELSE '' END
    + ' as [' + c.name + ']'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)

EXEC('SELECT ' + @currColumns + ' FROM ' + @tableName);
```

It's a quick and dirty way.

UPDATE (comment):
Inserting into a table is really easy.  Just do this:

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE]
EXEC('SELECT ' + @currColumns + ' FROM ' + @tableName);
```

Comment: The code does not seem to work. In the first select statement I don't know where we got the t.name and c.name

Comment: Thanks Rogala. The above code works, but the issue is what if the first column is a VARCHAR. It appends quotes at the end of the first column value but does not append it at the beginning.

Comment: Do you know how I can insert the EXEC(SQL QUERY) into a temp table?

Comment: Updated, you could also do this in your script itself and then process the temp table in the script